# API in Rails, info not displaying, unsure how to get the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to use this API on my website: https://apidocs.tokeet.com/. When I use the curl command I can see the json output in my terminal, so I know I’m connected to it, but I don't know how to integrate it on my rails website itself.
When I paste from the api docs:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://capi.tokeet.com/v1/rental?account={{account}}")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["Authorization"] = "{{apikey}}"
request.body = "{}"

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

into my controller, the output I'm getting is []. It’s doing something, but not what I’d like it to do. I just need the GET action to display things on a page.

My main questions for now are:

- do I need to create a controller/api/v1 version or can I use my regular controller?
- do I need to create a views/api/v1 folder for my views or do I use the regular views?
- how do I translate the variables from the API ("city", "bathrooms", etc") to my views?

I’m quite new at this and although I’ve integrated an API before, that documentation was more guiding than this one. Could someone help me with my questions and provide a good resource or some guidance on how to continue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it's not working on your controller but you are not showing your controller

Comment: Try setting the debug output on the http object, maybe you have some information there https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-set_debug_output

Comment: ```def index
    url = URI("https://capi.tokeet.com/v1/rental?account=accountnumbergivenbytokeet")

    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request["Authorization"]=ENV['TOKEET_API']
    request.body = "{}"

    response = https.request(request)
    puts response.read_body
@apartments = Apartment.all
end``` That's my complete code up to now, it's in the controller. I thought that's where it should be, but I'm not sure. ```json.array! @apartments do |apartment|
  json.extract! apartment, :id, :city
end
```

Comment: Hi Ariel, thank you for your comments! This code is in my controller and in my view - do you think these are correct? It's giving me an empty array. I will have a closer look at the link you put in your comment, hoping to clear this road block soon!

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that part of the URL you have is wrong.
instead of {{account}} there should be a dynamic indentifier of some kind. and you just send the string {{account}}. the server most likely does not know such accounts.
that is in your case the URL should look something like this:

```
url = URI("https://capi.tokeet.com/v1/rental?account=#{account_id}")
```

or

```
url = URI("https://capi.tokeet.com/v1/rental?account=" + account_id)
```

instead

```
url = URI("https://capi.tokeet.com/v1/rental?account={{account}}")
```

account_id is a variable that must contain a unique identifier that can look like anything, for example
account_id = "01a04f03s34".
and that's just one of the problems.
the same goes for {{apikey}} about uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’ve put the account Id in my actual code and the api key in my .env file. I can see the json output in my terminal, but I don’t know how to get it onto my website. Any hints or tips would be welcome.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean about the website.
just like in the program.
if you managed to log in through your program using ID and apikey. then try to place the code in Action in Rails application. then, deploy the application to the hosting. in the control panel, register your application with the Api provider and get all the keys and identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the wrong thing, needed to put the code into a model. I didn't know, thought it was the controller. Everything is working now. Thanks to everyone for their help!